# Selecting half a document

Tags: text

I have an extremely long document in text edit that I want to delete roughly half of. Is there a better way to do this than selecting by clicking and scrolling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the text is at the second half of the document, go to the beginning of the text You want to delete and press <kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>↓ DOWN ARROW</kbd> and then delete it.
If it's in the first half, go to the beginning of the text You do not want to delete and press <kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>↑ UP ARROW</kbd> and delete it.